# Direct2D Equivalent for IOS OSX development

Tags: c++, ios, macos, ipad, osx-mavericks

I am developing a user interface for my application.... most of my application is portable as is written in c++ but today I started thinking about the UI. Which is currently written in Direct2D. I was wondering if there was an equivalent for developing a UI in IOS(Ipad), and OSX(MAC)?

Something high level enough that I could draw rectangles and circles, but also low level enough that is not as slow as GDI.

Thanks in advance.

PS. I DON'T want comparing which are better or worse, I just want to know what options I have.

Comment: This is not really the kind of question that can be answered on this site as it invites discussion and personal opinion which leads to poor quality answers. However, that said, if it's for a game, then you can use something like Cocos2d, which is cross platform and reasonably performant. If you want to go native, then you could use [CoreGraphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coregraphics/reference/coregraphics_framework/_index.html) on the mac/ios. Bear in mind that interaction models differ between touch & mouse devices.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that kind of outcome from this question. I am not asking what people prefer to use but what are the options I have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreAnimation is a GPU-accelerated framework. Individual views are cached on the GPU. You can then apply composition arbitrary transforms to them. Such transforms are applied by the GPU to the cached image. So you can use CoreGraphics to draw a circle, rectangle or whatever, have CoreAnimation store that bitmap on the GPU and then transform that.

Also from the first-party frameworks, Sprite Kit provides a game-oriented framework that includes game-style (ie, accelerated write-once read-many 'sprites') drawing alongside physics/etc.

OpenGL ES is also fully supported. You can assume 2.0 is always available as it was introduced on the 3GS and Apple no longer accepts binaries for older devices. 3.0 is also available on the latest iPhone. That's obviously quite a bit lower level than Direct2D but Apple supplies GLKit which allows you to upload images trivially and to emulate the old fixed-functionality pipeline with just a few simple calls.

Out in the third-party world I guess the main thing people are going to suggest is [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) but at this point it's already playing catch-up to Sprite Kit.

Of those, CoreAnimation, OpenGL and Cocos2D span iOS and OS X with some minor differences, Sprite Kit is already available on iOS and will turn up in the next OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very informative. I need to start studying me some Cocoa programming so I can port my UI code.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Cocoa (OSX) and Cocoa Touch (iOS). In apps made with those you can use Core Graphics which seems like a good fit for your needs, or OpenGL which is probably overkill. Of course there are many 3rd party libraries you can use, Cocos2d as Petesh mentioned is one of them.